# Rewrite xml and save context

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've XML strings like the following:

```
xml = """
<body>
    <head>1. Un livre sur <persName type="author" key="Ronsard, Pierre de (1524-1585)" ref="http://www.idref.fr/027107957">Ronsard</persName></head>
    <head>2. <title>La pitié des églises</title> par <persName key="Barrès, Maurice (1862-1923)" ref="http://www.idref.fr/026706601" type="author">Barrès</persName></head>
</body>
"""
```

I've some function called `processLine(line)` that takes a whole line ( text within `<head>` without tags), in my case these two lines will be processed by the `processLine`function:

```
1. Un livre sur Ronsard
2. La pitié des églises par Barrès
```

and concatenate a certain string to some words of each line, for example:

```
"Ronsard" becomes "Ronsard I-PER"
"Barrès"  becomes "Barrès I-PER"
```

Here is the code I've made so far using Python's etree library:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
pars = root.xpath('//body//head')

for par in pars:
    line = par.text # return the line stripped from tags
    processLine( line )
```

**My Question:** How can I save those changes in the xml file, without loosing its structure ?

ie: My new XML file in my exemple will become:

```
newxml = """
<body>
    <head>1. Un livre sur <persName type="author" key="Ronsard, Pierre de (1524-1585)" ref="http://www.idref.fr/027107957">Ronsard I-PER</persName></head>
    <head>2. <title>La pitié des églises</title> par <persName key="Barrès, Maurice (1862-1923)" ref="http://www.idref.fr/026706601" type="author">Barrès I-PER</persName></head>
</body>
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tag' `text` property to what you need and then just call `etree.tostring(rootElt, prettyPrint = True)`.

Yeah, and note: I'm selecting all the `<persName>` tags, not all the headings itselves:

```
pars = root.xpath('//body//head//persName')
```

Check this out:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<body>
    <head>1. Un livre sur <persName type="author" key="Ronsard, Pierre de (1524-1585)" ref="http://www.idref.fr/027107957">Ronsard</persName></head>
    <head>2. <title>La pitié des églises</title> par <persName key="Barrès, Maurice (1862-1923)" ref="http://www.idref.fr/026706601" type="author">Barrès</persName></head>
</body>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
pars = root.xpath('//body//head//persName')

for par in pars:
    line = par.text # return the line stripped from tags
    processLine( line ) 

    par.text = par.text + ' I-PER'

print(etree.tostring(root, unicode = True, pretty_print = True))
```

This prints the following XML:

```
<body>
    <head>1. Un livre sur <persName type="author" key="Ronsard, Pierre de (1524-1585)" ref="http://www.idref.fr/027107957">Ronsard I-PER</persName></head>
    <head>2. <title>La pitié des églises</title> par <persName key="Barrès, Maurice (1862-1923)" ref="http://www.idref.fr/026706601" type="author">Barrès I-PER</persName></head>
</body>
```

If you want to process all the headings and only then process names - may be you want to select inner tag (`persName`) from heading tag itself (`head`)?

```
for par in pars:
    # ...

    pers = par.xpath('//persName')

    for per in pers:
        per.text = per.text + ' I-PER'
```

This code gives exactly the same result, but within the `processLine` function you will still deal with the whole `<head>` tag, whilst `pers` variable will contain all that tag's `<persName>` children.